# Why so many classes declared as abstract even it contain all defined methods?

Tags: model, architecture

For example these classes are abstract Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract,Mage_Core_Model_Abstract etc.But it contain only defined methods.and what is the necessity to given class as abstract.
I know abstract class how to declare and rules.But i need more real time example(like magento).
Even i deleted abstract keyword before class name.but its not giving any error.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A class can be declared as abstract for 2 reasons.

1. It contains abstract methods
2. That class should not be instantiated.

In magento's case most of the abstract classes fall in the second case.
Classes like `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract` and `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` are never instantiated. They are just used as a common ancestor for other classes.
Just search in the code for `extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

The "abstract" classes contain common behavior of all child classes but they don't actually do something without some configuration values.

Let's take for example `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`. This is a common model for all other models that map to one table (or more tables for the eav entities).  But the base class should never be instantiated.
For example you can call `$model->save()` on a child class because that one has a mapping to (at least) a table but you cannot call it on the abstract class. But the `save` method works the same for all the child models so no need to implement it in all the child classes.

I hope I was clear enough.